# full-width table of content for tufte-book

Tags: tufte, tufte-book

Using the tufte-book layout, I wish to use the full width of the pages where the table of content is listed. There are a number of similar questions on SO ([for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121790/how-to-generate-a-full-width-table-of-contents-tufte-book) from which I used some of his example code, or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610481/the-tableofcontents-in-tcolorbox-without-title-contents) where Ulrike Fischer suggested part of a solution.

I found somewhere a suggestion that `tcolorbox` could be used and have found that it works, even in cases where the table of content is longer than a page.

I have a MWE which works nearly; can it be made to work correctly?

It does either

- insert multiple empty pages before the TOC starts (when using `\tableofcontent`), or
- starts without header (when using `\csname @starttoc\endcsname{toc}`)
  (if I add a `\clearpage` then I get multiple empty pages)

In either case, the text for the even pages is completely outside of the box.

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,showframe] 
         {tufte-book}  
\usepackage{printlen} % to print geometry
\usepackage{calc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}  
\usepackage[]{mdframed}

\title{TITEL book level 1 BookTitle}
\author{Author of Settings}

\usepackage[breakable,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document} 
\frontmatter  

        \vspace{1.5cm}
        {\huge\bfseries{TITEL book level 1 BookTitle} \par}     
        {\large \today\par}
        
%    \clearpage
    \tcbset{breakable,%
%           title=Content title,%
            width=\textwidth,%
            grow to right by=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[toggle enlargement=evenpage]
%       \tableofcontents
%       \clearpage
         \csname @starttoc\endcsname{toc}
    \end{tcolorbox}

\mainmatter
\section{book title - one hash: vorwort buch v12345}
vorwort some text

\chapter{Questions of Design}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Drawing}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Technique}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Design}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found using an updated `tufte-common.def` where I fixed what I think is a problem in the lines `\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{}{%
  % Forces internal LaTeX `twoside'
%  \geometry{asymmetric} % seems wrong
  \geometry{twoside}  % swaps the margins
}
` with this, the output looks fine.